# Validate token generated by MSAL in an AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, azure-ad-msal

I have been looking for a solution for the following problem:

I am currently developing an application in Angular where I use the MSAL library to authenticate with the active directory and from my web application I obtain the authentication token.

I want to send this token in the HTTP header to an AWS API Gateway through a lambda so that it can execute the services exposed by the API, does anyone have an example of how this implementation could be done?

Comment: Did you find a solution, @damanchola ? I am trying something similar.